# Matching views using layout resource id's with Espresso?

Tags: android, hamcrest, android-espresso

I'm writing test automation for our Android app with Espresso. How can I check if a view with a specific layout resource is being displayed? Assume I have a layout resource `activity_1.xml`. in `res/layout`. Using matcher `withId(R.layout.activity_1)` doesn't work. Neither does `withResource("activity_1")`. I often can't match with viewgroup id's because they're shared between multiple other viewgroups making them unreliable. I also would prefer to write the tests in isolation without having to touch any layout attributes.

Comment: What I do is create an id in the first viewgroup (relativelayout, linearlayout, coordinatorlayout, framelayout...) as, for example, android:id="@+id/activity1_wrapper" and then in the espresso code use the matcher withId(r.id.activity1_wrapper) and check it's visibility. I found no other way.

Comment: The problem is that the id of the first viewgroup is shared between multiple other viewgroups across the resource base, so i cannot rely on that.

Comment: Ok. But it must be one element whih is not shared, you can check that id of the unique element and that is descendant of a view with the id of that wrapper id, for example